# rails 3.2 check if hidden field has value while sending form

Tags: forms, validation, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have inside of a form one hidden field, which must be  empty when the form is submitted.

Is any value in it, i want to set a flag in the database column.

How can i realize the check if the value of this hidden field is not filled?
Is it an issue for controllers or for models?

Answer (score 0):

It is an issue for the controller. You want to check the value of that field in the `create` and `update` actions and store what ever you want to store there.